# Find eigenvalues anf eigenvectors of $f(p(x)):=p'(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Find eigenvalues anf eigenvectors of $f \in \operatorname{End}(P_{3}^{R}[x])$, where $f(p(x)):=p'(x)$

I have calculated the linear map matrix in standard basis and then I've applied the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, which gave me this determinant:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  -\lambda&1&0&0\\
  0&-\lambda&2&0\\
0&0&-\lambda&3\\
0&0&0&-\lambda
\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

which only eigenvalue is $\lambda = 0$. Hence, the only eigenvector would be $(1,0,0,0)$.

Is this process correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computations are correct, but the answer is not, since $(1,0,0,0)\notin P_3^{\mathbb R}[x]$. The eigenvectors corresponding to the null eigenvalue are the constant polynomials.

Comment: But using the method to obtain eigenvectors, in this case, as $\lambda = 0$, we have that the solutions for the matrix equation $A*(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ are $x = \mu$ (parameter), $y = 0$, $z = 0$, $t= 0$. Do you mean that the eigenvector is $p(x) = 1$?

Comment: Almost. I mean that $p(x)=1$ is **an** eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$. I hope that you agree that the eigenvectors must belong to the space that you are working with.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that remark. So the eigenvectors corresponding to 0 could be any number, like $p(x)= 4$ or $p(x)=-7$, for example, right?

Comment: Yes, it can be any *non-null* constant polynomial. That's always true for eigenvectors: if $v$ is an eigenvector and $\lambda\neq0$, then $\lambda v$ is an eigenvector too.

Comment: Allright, it's all clear. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a nilpotent endomorphism since $f^4\equiv0$. Indeed, $\displaystyle \frac{d^4}{dx^4}f(x)=0$ for every polynomial of degree at most $3$. Hence $0$ is the unique eigenvalue and it has algebraic multiplicity $1$. The eigenspace corrisponding to $0$ is the kernel of $f$, namely the subspace of those polynomiasl whose first derivative is zero, namely constant polynomials.

Now: $P_3^{\Bbb R}$ naturally identifies with $\Bbb R^4$ by the map $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3\longmapsto (a, b, c, d)$. By using this identification, the subspace corresponding to constant polynomials is the subspace generated by $(1,0,0,0)$. I think you have used this identification in your mind. However, what you have written is not properly correct unless you specify that you are using this identification and working with $\Bbb R^4$ instead of $P_3^{\Bbb R}$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method without matrices. If $p(x)$ is an eigenvector then $\exists \lambda$ such that

$$ p'(x) = \lambda p(x).$$

If $p(x)$ is a non constant polynomial then we now that the degree of $p'(x)$ is less than the degree of $p(x)$ and we cannot have  $p'(x) = \lambda p(x)$.

Therefore $p(x)$ must be a constant polynomial and we have the equation 
$$ p'(x) = 0 = \lambda p(x)$$
and we must have $\lambda = 0$ and $p(x)$ constant.